# Prevent flows from writing sensitive data to debug logs in plaintext

Tags: visual-workflow, security, debug-logs

We have a screen flow that collects a password from the user using a Password field component. That masks the input on screen, but when looking at debug logs, the value of that field gets written to the debug log in plain text. Is there a way to flag that field so it doesn't get written to a debug log?

Comment: Create/use a managed package for the screen flow?  this way the debug log is not visible

Answer (score 0):

This is a great use case for implementing a more robust logging framework like  [NebulaLogger](https://github.com/jongpie/NebulaLogger). [It comes with OOTB support for metadata-driven masking rules](https://github.com/jongpie/NebulaLogger#features).

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Furthermore, Nebula or other higher-level logging solutions only solve the masking problem for its own logs. For admins with access to debug logs, there's no way to mask. (SF recently started masking some passwords in debug but that only covers a small % of use cases)